# How to put a matrix like this image?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I don't know if this is the place where I can ask this. If not, please, tell me where.

This is a particular example of matrix I want to write in TeX commands. I was searching matrix stuff in "MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference" but, supossing I searched well, any of them makes a separation-lines between some blocks I want to distinguish.
If it's possible, I also want the "big zero $0$ (a null matrix)" and the "big $I_{n-r}$ (identity matrix)" instead of the regular letter size.

[image]

Comment: If you want separating lines, you will probably have to use array like [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13495/vertical-bar-in-matrix-appearing-twice) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820340/multiplication-of-block-matrix). I am not sure what is the best solution to get symbols $0$ and $I$ larger in this specific situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess, something like

$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\end{matrix}&\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\end{matrix}\\\hline
\huge{\mathbf O}&\huge{\mathbf I_{n-2}}\end{array}\right)$$

(right-click and select "Show Math As" > "TeX Commands" to see the code)